# reject code 8.1

Tags: ios, software-update, app-store-connect

8.1 Details

Your app does not comply with the Guidelines for Using Apple's Trademarks and Copyrights. Specifically, your app icon contained a likeness of an iOS device.

We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference.(i have got a my logo screenshot)

Next Steps

Please revise your app and its metadata to address these trademark issues.

---

when i uploading the first, it have not a trouble, but i did update when 2week ago and reject.(and apple give to me a guide line linkhttp://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html)
i add some icons and splash images for using as under ver.iOS8. and submit.
cause it was simple update, i don't mind that but reject.
what can i do for this situation?(logo size was exactly corrected. and same design)

Comment: The issue is not size but trademark - you need to show Apple that you have the legal right to use what they think is a trademarked logo

Comment: thanks mark. i send a message to the Apple. this app was passed last time but this time is not......... IT IS A SAME ICONNNNNNNNN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has the right to reject app icons that contain a picture of an iPhone or an iPad. The [Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html) explain why Apple does not support such icons:

> **Depictions of Apple Products**
>
> Apple does not support the use of […] images of Apple products by other parties in marketing, promotional or advertising materials as their use may create the perception that Apple endorses or sponsors the product, service or promotion.

Go through all your splash images and your icons, especially the app icon. Remove all pictures that look like an iPhone or an iPad. After that, re-submit your app.

Comment: wating plaese i dont understand what i del the icon in Xcode. i del the red name file? it is splash but not icon

Comment: ok, i exactly understand this metter. reject reason was just 'my icon included seem like iOS devices' whether i think that or not......